# Python Flickr API, small error in code

Tags: python, flickr

```
import flickrapi

api_key = "xxxxxx"
secret_api_key = "xxxxxxx"
flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, secret_api_key)

def obtainImages():

photo_list = flickr.photos.search(api_key=api_key, has_geo=1,         format='parsed-json', extras = 'tags')

    for photo in photo_list[0]:
        print photo.attrib['title']

obtainImages()
```

I want to import all images from flickr with a geo-tag, and I want to simply print the title out of these images for now. However I am getting an error saying "line 11, in obtainImages for photo in photo_list[0]: KeyError: 0"
I know its probably just a simple issue but any help in fixing it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Probably `flickr.photos.search` returns a dict but you try to use it like an array.

Comment: Yeah `parsed-json` probably results in a dict being returned. print the contents of `photo_list` to know more.